# How can this behavior be acomplished? Python "short circuting" test

Tags: python, short-circuiting

I have the following code:

```
def testGeodatabase(self):
    geodatabaseList = self.gp.ListWorkspaces("*","ALL")
    for x in geodatabaseList:
        if x == self.outputGeodatabase:
            return True
        else:
            pass
    return False
```

What i need to know the following: in case the if condition evaluates to true, will the function stop looking in the list and never return False? Or do i need a break statement?

```
def testGeodatabase(self):
    geodatabaseList = self.gp.ListWorkspaces("*","ALL")
    for x in geodatabaseList:
        if x == self.outputGeodatabase:
            return True
            break
        else:
            pass
    return False
```

If the following code does not solve my problem, what can i use to do simulate that behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`return` is the end of the line, and nothing else will happen in that function afterwards. On the other hand, you could rewrite your function as

```
def testGeodatabase(self):
    return self.outputGeodatabase in self.gp.ListWorkspaces("*","ALL")
```

Comment: thank you very much. Very pythonic :P

In this case, if the self.outputGeodatabase does not exist in the list, will that cause the function to return None or False? My bet is None...

Comment: No need to risk your money... try it! `print 'a' in ('b','c')`

Comment: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#in scroll down to "The operators in and not in test for collection membership."

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the break keyword in the code above. Actually, you don't need the

```
else:
   pass
```

either. The

```
return True
```

will exit the function.

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement will indeed cause the function to be exited at that point. No further code is executed in the function.

Here is a simple test which you could run to prove the point:

```
def someFunction(nums):
    for i in nums:
        if i == 1:
            return "Found 1!"
    return "Never found 1"
```

And running it:

```
>>> someFunction([2])  
'Never found 1'  
>>> someFunction([2,1,3])  
'Found 1!'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that using `any()` is the best choice:

```
def testGeodatabase(self):
    geodatabaseList = self.gp.ListWorkspaces("*","ALL")
    return any(x == self.outputGeodatabase for x in geodatabaseList)
```